# Name for a Partition in which Every Block Has the Same Size

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a standard name for a partition of a set in which every block (i.e. the subsets comprising the partition) has the same size? Regular? Uniform? Something else? Nothing else (so I'm free to make up my own)?

Comment: This paper uses the term *uniform*: http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_12/PDF/v12i1r40.pdf.

Comment: I've seen [$k$-subset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Subset.html) partition being used...

Comment: Apparently, the term *$k$-regular* could mean something very different: http://math.furman.edu/~dpenn/Research/lregularpreprint.pdf and http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~lovejoy/3regular.pdf. (Note: I have no experience with this field. I just picked the top results from google.)